# Wildfly: Many open libraries

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8, lsof

I have an Java EE application which runs fine with wildfly 8.2.0 but after some days uptime there are many open files (170000+). After checking the system with "lsof" I found for many lines with open libraries (jar files).

For example:

```
lsof | grep "wildfly-jpa-8\.2\.0\.Final\.jar" | wc -l
or
lsof | grep "wildfly-batch-8\.2\.0\.Final\.jar" | wc -l
```

This gives me 216 lines.

```
lsof | grep "\.jar" | wc -l
```

Returns 97092 lines.

This can't be normal. Currently its not possible for me to reproduce this behavior. The page is highly frequently used therefore I run jmeter, on a test-server with the same setup, with 100 threads which navigates through the page for an hour but the open files did not increased more than 65000 open files for the whole system (lsof | wc -l).

Comment: Try with http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/

Comment: Exploded deployment?

Comment: I migrated the last days to Wildfly 9.0.2 and the problems seems to be fixed. But I will wait some days and monitor the systems.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of lsof include a thread id. This can be determined by the TID column header apparent in the output. Such an output will give rise to a duplication of entries since lsof will potentially show duplicated entries one for each thread.

https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/209826153-lsof-shows-Cassandra-is-holding-a-large-amount-of-files-open